# Dynamic CSS selection within a group, SVG, Path

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, path

I'm learning CSS and working on a problem involving dynamic color selection of a path.

I've a `SVG` which can have any number of paths (1+) and there are pre-defined colors which should be assigned to paths depending on their order. (A web service returns a collection of paths).

For simplicity, Let's say I've 4 known paths and there are two colors possible: Green and deepPink.

**Question:** How can I assign following colors dynamically (without creating individual classes for each path):

- Path1: Green
- Path2: deepPink
- Path3: Green
- Path4: deepPink

```css
.path_group {
  stroke="black";
  fill="none";
  stroke-width="2";
}

.myPath{
  stroke:deepPink;
  stroke-width:1.3;
}

/*
Color1: Green
Color2: deepPink
*/
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 260 200"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g class="path_group" >
    <path class="myPath" d="M10,25 L110,10" />
    <path class="myPath" d="M10,35 L110,20" />
    <path class="myPath" d="M10,45 L110,30" />
    <path class="myPath" d="M10,55 L110,40" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

I'm more interested in doing it in natively using CSS/JS instead of adding any framework or library to my project. Suggestion regarding any particular concept is appreciated.

**Demo**: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/rohitkandhal/pen/buIBG)

**Current approach**

```
this.colors = ["green", "deepPink"];

this.getColor = function (pathIndex) {
    return this.colors[pathIndex % this.colors.length];
};
```

Comment: Typically dynamic CSS isn't a good idea  (at least that's what I've been told)

Comment: you would add classes to each, unless especially when you repeat colours, or else you could use a colour range, like the ones when you plot charts.

Comment: I added a code sample. Currently, whenever I create a new SVG I call the getColor method with the index of path and set the color returned as hard coded value in svg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS3 `:nth-child()` selector ([w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)) as this:

```
.myPath { stroke-width:1.3; }

.path_group .myPath:nth-child(4n+1)
{ stroke:red; }
.path_group .myPath:nth-child(4n+2)
{ stroke:blue; }
.path_group .myPath:nth-child(4n+3)
{ stroke:green; }
.path_group .myPath:nth-child(4n+4)
{ stroke:deepPink; }
```

See updated codepen [**here**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/owpir).